# Property of a symmetry under polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider $u_n$ such that for $P \in \mathbb{R}_n\left[X\right]$
$$
u_n\left(P\right)\left(X\right)=X^nP\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)
$$

I wanted to find Im$\left(u_n\right)$ and Ker$(u_n)$.\

I know that $u_n$ exists and is a symmetry on $\mathbb{R}_n\left[X\right]$. We have
$$
u_n\left(P\right)=0 \Rightarrow P\left(\frac{1}{X}\right)=0\Rightarrow P=0
$$
Hence $u_n$ is injective, then bijective because dim$\left(\mathbb{R}_n\left[X\right]\right)=n+1<+\infty$.

Am I right ? I'm doubting.

Can I write that $u_n=2p_n-\text{Id}$
 where$ p_n$ is a projection on $\mathbb{R}_n\left[X\right]$ ?

Comment: Indeed, its a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

$u_n$ is a bijection and $p_n(p_n(P))=P$. Also $p_n$ is the projection on the space of all polynomials $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_ix^{i}$ with $a_i=a_{n-i}$ for all $i$.

Comment: I've seen that if $s$ is a symmetry on $E$, then $s=2p-\text{Id}$ where $p$ is a projection on its image parralelle to its kernel. So $p_n=(1/2)(u_n+\text{Id})$ is a projection on $\mathbb{R}_n\left[X\right]$ and its kernel is the polynomials such that $u_n(P)=-P$ ?